# Having Issues with pandas groupby.mean() not ignoring NaN as expected

Tags: python, pandas, std, nan, mean

Im currently trying to get the mean() of a group in my dataframe (tdf), but I have a mix of some NaN values and filled values in my dataset. Example shown below

| Test # | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | NaN |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 |

My code needs to take this dataset, and make a new dataset containing the mean, std, and 95% interval of the set.

```
i = 0 
num_timeframes = 2 #writing this in for example sake
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = tdf.columns)
while i < num_timeframes:
  results = tdf.loc[tdf["Test #"] == i].groupby(["Test #"]).mean()
  new_df = pd.concat([new_df,results])
  results = tdf.loc[tdf["Test #"] == i].groupby(["Test #"]).std()
  new_df = pd.concat([new_df,results]) 
  results = 2*tdf.loc[tdf["Test #"] == i].groupby(["Test #"]).std()
  new_df = pd.concat([new_df,results])
  new_df['Test #'] = new_df['Test #'].fillna(i) #fill out test number values
  i+=1
```

For simplicity, i will show the desired output on the first pass of the while loop, only calculating the mean. The problem impacts every row however. The expected output for the mean of Test # 1 is shown below:

| Test # | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1.5 |

However, columns which contain any NaN rows are calculating the entire mean as NaN resulting in the output shown below

| Test # | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | NaN |

I have tried passing skipna=True, but got an error stating that mean doesn't have a skipna argument. Im really at a loss here because it was my understanding that df.mean() ignores NaN rows by default. I have limited experience with python so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by removing the groupby function entirely (I was looking through it and realized I had no reason to call groupby here other than benefit from groupby keeping my columns in the correct orientation). Figured I'd post my fix in case anyone ever comes across this.

```
for i in range(num_timeframes):
  results = tdf.loc[tdf["Test #"] == i].mean()
  results = pd.concat([results, tdf.loc[tdf["Test #"] == i].std()], axis = 1)
  results = pd.concat([results, 2*tdf.loc[tdf["Test #"] == i].std()], axis = 1)
  results = results.transpose()
  results["Test #"] = i
  new_df = pd.concat([new_df,results])
  new_df.loc[new_df.shape[0]] = [None]*len(new_df.columns)
```

All i had to do was transpose my results because df.mean() flips the dataframe for some reason which is likely why I had tried using groupby in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
DataFrame.mean( axis=None, skipna=True)
```

Comment: Error: mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
For some reason, I can't pass the arguments associated with mean()

Comment: Is it possible there are multiple mean() methods and its using the wrong one? I have pandas, canterra, and math imported (in that order)